# Is it anti-pattern to 'require' inside componentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs

Is it anti-pattern to 'require' inside componentWillMount? I'm trying to dynamically load a locale based on the current user region.

```
componentWillMount(){
 if (localStorage.getItem('locale') === 'da') {
  require('moment/locale/da')
  moment.locale('da')
 }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please note that `componentWillMount` seems to be deprecated in newer versions of React - so I guess it would become a anti-pattern; https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0006-static-lifecycle-methods.md

Comment: what is the use case here that makes will mount the better choice than did mount?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what tool to bundle the code you're using, the result may vary. If you use Webpack, it will resolve "require" and "import" in-place, not skipping class methods or anything. It means you won't really benefit much from this. The bundle size won't be optimal, but you'll likely increase the chance of shooting in the foot.

However, in Webpack 3, there's a feature called **lazy loading** in Webpack that allows you to require a module on the run-time. Webpack will take care of putting all the necessary JS code on the run-time in user's browser to require the module from server and execute it (think creating a "script" element and appending it to `document`).

There's [a note on lazy loading in official Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) that points at potential difference in implementation of this feature across different libraries. With this, the code would look like

```
async componentDidMount() { // <- note that componentWillMount isn't the best place to lazy-load a remote module, see @TryingToImprove's comment
  const da = await import('moment/locale/da'); // <- Webpack will add its magic here
  moment.locale(da);
}
```

Also, read more on [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports).

So, answering your question

> Is it anti-pattern to 'require' inside componentWillMount?

I'm afraid it still is in early 2018, at least in a way you described, and unless special care is taken of it.

ESLint actually has a rule for that, [global-require](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require), that automatically waves a flag when an "import" or "require" statement stands anywhere except global scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you require modules at runtime they won't be included while bundling and it will be undefined.

Comment: It depends highly on the bundler. Webpack will add `__webpack_import__(•)` in place of every "require", regardless of its position, so it will actually work and won't be undefined, although the whole purpose of requiring at that pace will be of no use, as compared to global require (on top of the module file).